# How to plot different colors and styles based on a column condition with adjust text in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data, `df`

```
name   age    weight    is_friend
Joe     23      180           0
Jane    27      150           1
Josh    20      200           1
```

I want to color the point *and* text of the people who are my friend (`is_friend==1`). I am able to do this but need to subset the data and make two different plots. See the code below:

```
#subset
friend = df[(df.is_friend==1)
not_friend = df[(~df.is_friend==1)

#plot 1
ax.scatter(friend['age'], friend['weight'], alpha=.7, color='red')

texts = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom',color='red',style='italic') for x0,y0,name in zip(friend['age'], friend['weight'], friend.name)]

adjust_text(texts)

#plot 2
ax.scatter(not_friend['age'], not_friend['weight'],color='black')

texts1 = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom') for x0,y0,name in zip(not_friend['age'], not_friend['weight'], not_friend.name)]

adjust_text(texts1)
```

As seen above, I have to subset the data and create two different plots with color and style for the points and labels. This works, but there are exceptions:

Since there are two different `adjustText` objects, they don't work with eachother. The point of `adjustText` is to adjust the text so that labels look nice, however, with multiple datapoints, labels from `texts` and `texts1` overlap as they are not from the same object and accounting for each other. See below for an example of this with different data.

[image]

I was wondering if I could use an `if else` statement to not only shorten this code but make sure no points overlap. Here is what I tried that resulted in an error:

```
if df['is_friend'] == 1:
  texts = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom',color='red',style='italic') for x0,y0,name in zip(df['age'], df['weight'], df.name)]
else:
  texts = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom') for x0,y0,name in zip(df['age'], df['weight'], df.name)]

adjust_text(texts))
```

However, I get the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Again, I am trying to change the color of certain labels and points within an `adjustText` object without having to create two different plots and thus a possibility of overlapping points and a longer run time due to more code. I would really appreciate any help here. Thanks!

Comment: In your first code block, couldn't you simply concatenate both lists and call `adjust_text(texts+texts1)`?

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @JohanC, concatenating both texts would solve your problem. However, calling `scatter` once is more ideal of course. You can make a list of colours that are based on your friend logic and pass that to both `scatter` and `text`:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cond_color, cond_alpha, cond_style = [], [], []
for f in df['is_friend']:
    cond_color.append('r' if f==1 else 'grey')
    cond_alpha.append(0.2 if f==1 else 1)
    cond_style.append('italic' if f==1 else None)

cond_color2 = np.asarray([(*mpl_c.to_rgb(c), a) for c,a in zip(cond_color, cond_alpha)])
ax.scatter(df['age'], df['weight'], c=cond_color2)

texts = [plt.text(x0, y0, name, color=c, style=sty) for x0,y0,name,c,sty in zip(df['age'], df['weight'], df.index, cond_color, cond_style)]
plt.show()
```